# Extracting nucleotide sequence from a non-standardly formatted text file

Tags: regex, perl

I have been given some DNA sequences by collaborators in a word document that I'd like to convert into a series of fasta sequences in one file.

I've made it into a text file and I figured that using regular expressions to extract the gene name and the sequence:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

die "usage: make_fasta.pl <sequence file>" unless (@ARGV == 1);

my $seq_filename    = shift;
my $fasta_db_name   = $seq_filename . "_db.fa";

open(my $seq_file, '<', $seq_filename) 
          or die "can't open file $seq_filename, $!";
open(my $fasta_file, '>', $fasta_db_name) 
          or die "can't open file $fasta_db_name, $!";

while (my $line = <$seq_file>) {
    chomp $line;
    if ($line =~ /^[ATCG]+$/) { # if the line is entirely DNA seqence
       print $fasta_file "$line\n";            

    } elsif ($line =~ /Full-length (\w+) cDNA/) { # if the line has gene info
        print $fasta_file ">$1\n";

    } else {
        next;

    } 
}
```

But that just gave me the name of the first gene. Clearly I've done something wrong with the DNA regular expression but I can't for the life of me work it out. To my eyes it's exactly the same as other suggested DNA tests I've found on this site and others.

The file I'm trying to parse is configured like so:

```
Collaborators name

title of gene set

Full-length clock cDNA coding sequence 

ATGGTAGGATGTGTAATGCGTACGTGATCGT

Full-length per cDNA coding sequence

ATGCTAGCTACGTACGTAGCTACGTAGTACG
```

I want the output to be a fasta file so:

```
>clock
ATGGTAGGATGTGTAATGCGTACGTGATCGT
>per
ATGCTAGCTACGTACGTAGCTACGTAGTACG
```

The first few lines of the actual input file are:

```
Dr Lin Zhang (Leicester University 10/2012) 

Canonical clock genes 

Full-length per cDNA coding seq (3693bp) 

ATGGACACAGGAACACCCCATGAAGATGTGCCCTCAGAGGACCACACCTTGGAAGAAGGGGACAGCAAGAACCCCTCGTGCCAGCAAGAGTCAGCCTACGGCTCCCTCGAGTCATCCTCCAATGGACAGTCTCAGAAAAGTTTCGGAGGAAGTGGAAGCAAAAGCTTAAATAGTGGTTCGAGTCACAGCAGCGGCTTTGGGGACCAAAATGATTTCAAGGGTATCCATCTTCACGAAGCGAAACACATAGCGTTGAAGAAGAAGAAAACTGGGAAAGGAGGTGAAAAGGTAGCAGAAATCCCCTTTCAAACTGCCTCTGAGGCAGAACTGTCCTCCAAAGGAAACGAAACAGAAAAGGAGAAAGAAACAAGCCTCGAGGAGTCTCCTGCTGCAAAAGAGGAAGCAATTATCGAAAAGGAGTCTCGTTACATCCACCCGAGGAACT
```

Comment: How should look data structure of parsed input file?

Comment: Could it be that there is whitespace at the end of the line?

Comment: If I were to run the code you posted and give it an input file containing the example data you provided, what should the output be? (Assuming I first added "cDNA" to the end of the "Full length..." lines, of course.)

Answer (score 1):

Kind of hard to answer this question without seeing part of the actual input file.

There is a mis-match between your example input and your REGEX:

```
# looking for verbatim('Full-length') then <space> then one WORD_WITH_ALPHNUMERICS  then <space> and then verbatim 'cDNA'
$line =~ /Full-length (\w+) cDNA/;
```

Your example input line has 'Full length' without a dash, multiple words for the gene name not just one and no 'cDNA' at the end.

If your input line has 'Full-length **gene name with multiple words** cDNA', your REGEX can be:

```
$line=~/Full-length\s+(.*?)\s+cDNA/;
```

Comment: I've edited it so that the example actually makes sense (sorry I mocked up the example in a hurry)

Comment: The line I supplied should work fine.  You may want to use 'cDNA coding seq' instead of just cDNA e.g. $line=~/Full-length\s+(.*?)\s+cDNA coding seq/;   just to make it more specific but should work either way.  I've added the (.*?) construct in case there are multiple words used for the gene name - the '?' forces it to be less greedy about the match and stop matching as soon as it sees the cDNA - for example if there were two cDNA's on the line without the ? it would match on the second cDNA.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is apparently with your input data.  I modified the code you posted to produce the following program:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl    

use warnings;
use strict;

while (my $line = <DATA>) {
    chomp $line;
    if ($line =~ /^[ATCG]+$/) { # if the line is entirely DNA seqence
       print "$line\n";            
    } elsif ($line =~ /Full-length (\w+) cDNA/) { # if the line has gene info
        print ">$1\n";
    } 
}


__DATA__
Collaborators name

title of gene set

Full-length clock cDNA coding sequence 

ATGGTAGGATGTGTAATGCGTACGTGATCGT

Full-length per cDNA coding sequence

ATGCTAGCTACGTACGTAGCTACGTAGTACG
```

and it produces the output you specified:

```
~$ src/tmp/cdna 
>clock
ATGGTAGGATGTGTAATGCGTACGTGATCGT
>per
ATGCTAGCTACGTACGTAGCTACGTAGTACG
```

My modifications were only to make it self-contained and did not change any of the flow control or logic, aside from removing the useless `else { next }` clause.

Can you find and post a few lines of actual data which fails for you, since the dummy data provided seems to work correctly?

Comment: Adding that at either the beginning or the end of the `__DATA__` section, I still get output that appears correct. The per/clock names match the sequences they're displayed with instead of "sticking" or only displaying the first one.

Comment: How very strange... When I run your code with an external file it still just displays the first line. I really wanted to know if I was doing something stupid because I couldn't see why it wouldn't work.

Comment: Very odd indeed... I moved the `__DATA__` section out to a separate file and copy/pasted your `open` line to read that file and it still works fine. Can you try putting just the first two or three entries from your main data file into a new file by themselves and running that to see if you have problems? Then, if you do, that should be a small enough data sample to post here so that we can both test on the same input data.

Comment: I tried running the regular expression for the DNA on just a single sequence (no title line just a block of ATGCs) and it wouldn't work at all.

Comment: Perfect! What's the sequence that it fails on?

Comment: I think it was the page breaks from previously being a word document or something like that that was confusing perl